# How to retrieve $_GET variables from rewritten URLs?

Tags: url-rewriting, page-template

I need to receive some special $_GET parameters for a custom page I'm making, i know how to receive this through a simple $_GET like mysite.net/products/?id=1 , but I wanted to use the URL style of my WordPress like mysite.net/products/1.

How to retrieve $_GET variables from rewritten URLs?

Comment: I mistakenly close voted this as a duplicate...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be added on `init`:

To register your custom variable ('id' in the question)

```
add_rewrite_tag('%mycustomvar%','([^&]+)');
```

To create a re-write rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^product/([0-9]{1,})/?','index.php?p=4&mycustomvar=$matches[1]','top')
```

4 is the id of the 'product' page. You will need to flush rewrite rules once after adding these (go to Permalink settings page)

You can get the value of `mycustomvar`: `get_query_var( 'mycustomvar' )`.

See Codex for:

- [`add_rewrite_tag`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag)
- [`add_rewrite_rule`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)