# add_rewrite_rule ignoring other params than the "p" param

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

A specific post on my website has a shortcode that uses a parameter called "query" to produce its content. So, this is an example of a working URL:

```
https://example.com/my-post?query=980
```

"my-post" is the permalink of the post and the page is using the "query" param correctly.

However, we need to change this URL to a friendly one like https://example.com/something-here/980 and then I was trying to use the `add_rewrite_rule` like this:

```
function custom_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^something-here/([\d]+)$',
        'index.php?p=10219&query=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'custom_add_rewrite_rules');
```

When I try to access the friendly URL, I'm redirected to https://example.com/my-post successfully, but the **query** param is null (`$_GET["query"] = null`).

I also tried making use of `add_rewrite_tag` to register "query", but with no success.

If anyone has some light to shed it'd be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the plugin expects there to be a get param.

Your rewrite-rule is removing the get-param before it can be used by the plugin.

If the plugin hasn't been updated for a long time (it's abandonware) then you can go through the plugin and replace the get-param with the portion of the url which would have been the get-param. Just make sure to prevent the plugin from updating after you've made your edits.

If you add the following

```
function custom_add_rewrite_rules() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%query%','([^&]+)');

  add_rewrite_rule(
      '^something-here/([\d]+)$',
      'index.php?p=10219&query=$matches[1]',
      'top'
  );
}
add_action('init', 'custom_add_rewrite_rules');
```

& then replace 
`$_GET['query']` &/or `$_REQUEST['query]` with `get_query_var( 'query' )` in the plugin you've described, that should be enough to do the trick.

[Stephen Harris sums it up nicely in the answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48487/how-to-retrieve-get-variables-from-rewritten-urls)